# Equivalent in Java

Tags: java, objective-c

Taking me hours already to figure this out by googling and I think need help here. I have a snippet that is causing it not to work like its equivalent in objective c so would need some experts' help.

What are the equivalent of the objective c snippets below in java?

```
unsigned char mByte[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

uint64_t tBytes = 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

Answer (score 3):

Well there is no absolute equivalent, if all languages were the same why would we need more than one?

The closest thing is probably:

```
final int CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH = 1024; //some length
char[] mByte = new char[CC_SHAR1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

//there is no unsigned keyword in java
//The long data type is a 64-bit two's complement integer
long tBytes = Long.MAX_VALUE;
```

`long tBytes=0xFFFFFFFF;` would also work, but this is a negative number (because it is treated as an integer, not a long). If you want it to be long you need to add `L` (`0xFFFFFFFFL`) at the end. Be careful!
More info on the primitive datatypes can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Comment: You're mixing up `long` and `int`.  `0xFFFFFFFFL` is a perfectly valid nonnegative signed long.  `Long.MAX_VALUE` is `0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFL`, a much bigger number.

Comment: yes you are right, my bad. but still, you need the `L` at the end, otherwise `0xFFFFFFFF` will be `-1`.

Comment: 0xFFFFFFFFL is the correct one...You were right it was giving a negative  number without the L. Will flag this as the answer after I get to see char working

Answer (score 0):

unsigned char mByte[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
equivalent in java will be

> final int CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH=1024;
>
> byte mByte[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

though mByte is unsigned so when you work with mByte array you have to convert byte value to unsigned using 0xFF.
for example,
mByte[0]=(0x88 & 0xFF);

uint64_t tBytes = 0xFFFFFFFF;
equivalent in java will be

> long tBytes = 0xFFFFFFFF;

Answer (score 0):

Well the rule of thumb would be to match type lenght's in bits. 
In C unsigned char is 8 bit wide, so Java equivalent would be **byte**. 
In C uint64_t is 64 bit wide, so Java equivalent would be **long**. 
So therefore Java equivalent would be:

```java
//SHA1 lenght would be 20 bytes
public static final int CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH = 20;
byte mBytes[] = new byte[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
long tBytes = 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

@user3200809
mByte[0]=(0x88 & 0xFF); - this operation is pointless unless you have value larger than 8 bits. 
See the same operation in binary:

```java
 1000 1000
&
 1111 1111
=
 1000 1000
```

When assigning to mByte[i] you would have to type cast to byte anyway so all excessive bits will be chopped.

When we look at memory representation of those types there is no difference between signed and unsigned types.

I'm guessing from authors post that he works with SHA1 algorithm which is bunch of binary operations (xor's, and's, shift's). 
So for binary operations there is no difference that type is signed or unsigned:

```java
byte b = (byte) 0x80; //-128 in signed decimal
b ^= (byte) 0x01;
System.out.printf("0x%x", b); // prints 0x81 which is -127 in signed decimal
```

BUT you could run into problems if you're doing e.g. division.